# Generate next pseudo random value given a seed and offset

Tags: c++, c, linux, random

Is it possible, for a given implementation of `rand`, to efficiently generate the next number in the sequence given an initial seed and the number of calls to `rand` so far?

What I'd like is to use `rand` to provide a time offset for nodes in a simulation. Each node would seed with it's unique id and use the outputs of `rand` to provide jitter in delays in the simulation. I'd like each node to be able to calculate the next delay for any other node to measure collisions. I have access to the initial seed for any node and the number of times `rand` has been called.

I'd like to avoid having to seed and loop `n + 1` times to get the next value. Is what I want even possible with a generic linux implementation of `rand`?

Comment: No, but it's absolutely trivial to construct a mediocre pseudo-random number generator that has this property. Just use a cryptographic hash function on the seed and the loop counter. Are you coding in C or C++?

Comment: seed and loop is all I can think of, but if you cache your results you won't have to keep recalculating the same.  If you have an implementation where each output is the effective seed for the following output, you'll save on loops, but usually the output is only part of the following seed.

Comment: @David: C++ but I believe the interface is the same in either case and I could adapt as necessary - hence both tags.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @ezpz: You could adapt C++ code to C? I'm impressed. (If you think there's no difference, then there's no need or both. And if there is a relevant difference, stating both causes serious confusion.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Let me rephrase - I was claiming that the interface to `rand` is the same in either the C or C++ case. As I'm developing in C++ I'd be happy with a solution in either language.

Answer (score 1):

The random number generator in glibc is a Linear Congruential Generator, a generator on the form 
x_{n+1} = a * x_{n} + b mod m. For proper choice of a, b and m it may be adequate. Combining two or more improves the quality.

It is fairly easy to skip ahead in such a sequence.
x_{n+k} = a^{k} * x_{n} + b * (a^{k} - 1)/(a - 1) mod m. 
Raising a number to a power mod m is linear in the number of bits in the number, i.e. O(log(number)). To take the multiplicative inverse you just use the extended Euclidean algorithm. You only have to do the latter once.

Comment: Do you have code for that? Can’t understand the math but maybe could the implementation, or at least copy-paste it! Or do you have any extended reference to the subject? Thanks!